# How to implement calculation that needs non-associative reducer in mongodb mapreduce

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce

The question is better to be explained by an example:

A collection contains one document for one event, and the event can be either a "Start" event or a "Stop" event of some program.

For example, when program A start to run at time 12:00, it writes a document

```
{ program_name: 'A', time: 12:00, event: 'Start' }
```

When it is ended at 12:10, it writes another document

```
{ program_name: 'A', time: 12:10, event: 'Stop' }
```

So in the collection there are many pairs of Start-Stop document for different program.

**How can I calculate the elapsed time for each program by map reduce?**

For example, the map and reducer functions are:

```
function map() {
    emit( this.program_name, { time: this.time, event: this.event} )
}

function reduce(key, values) {
    var timeElapsed = 0
    if ( values[0].event == 'Start' ) {
        timeElapsed = values[1].time - values[0].time
    }
    else {
        timeElapsed = values[0].time - values[1].time
    }

    return timeElapse;
}
```

The above implementation gives the idea about what I want to do however it violates many [rules](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#requirements-for-the-reduce-function) says associative, idempotent and commutative.

**How to implement a mapreduce such that it conforms the mongodb reducer rules, or it is not possible to do so in mapreduce methodology?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reduce function could be like this:

```
function reduce(key, values) {
    return values.reduce((res, e) => Object.assign({[e.event]:e.time}, res, e), {})
}
```

The math should be done in [finalize](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#requirements-for-the-finalize-function) function:

```
function(key, reducedValue) {
    return reducedValue.Stop - reducedValue.Start;
}
```